Can't set custom resolution
my ubuntu-24.04 LTS,
rtx 3060 12gb|r 7 5700G
nvidia driver version-535.171.04
NVML Version-12.535.171.04
i did
cvt 1920 1440 160
xrandr --newmode "1920x1440_160.00"  680.25  1920 2096 2304 2688  1440 1443 1447 1583 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-2 1920x1440_160.00

but then it gives error:
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  64
  Current serial number in output stream:  65

i tried to go /etc/X11/xorg.conf, /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf, but there is no file xorg.conf

What video driver is being used?

@David updated, 535.171.04
